# Confusing pip SSL error on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation

I'm having an issue when using pip to install a package.

When I run `pip3 install pandas` I get:

`Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:646) - skipping`.

However, when I run `sudo -H python3 -m pip install pandas` pandas gets installed no problem.

I did a fair amount of googling, and I've been unable to understand what is wrong with using `pip3 install packageName`

for reference: when I run `which python3` the output is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3` and when I run `which pip3` the output is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip3`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `sudo -H which python3`? `sudo -H which pip3`?

Comment: `sudo -H which python3` `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3` @phd

Comment: `sudo -H which pip3`  `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3`

Comment: `which pip3` shows Python 3.5, is it true or mistyping? If that's true it's the difference you're looking for.

Comment: @phd you're correct. Is there a way to change the output of `which pip3` so that pip3 also uses python3.6? The solution I see commonly online is to use `python3 -m pip install packageName` as a workaround. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't *change the output of `which`* — you need to install `pip3` for Python 3.6. Inspect `$PATH` — which directory `bin` comes 1st — Python 3.5 or 3.6? List `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/` — is `pip3` there? If not — `python3.6 -m pip install pip`.